# package maven project with external jar

Tags: maven

I have used external jar in my maven project:

pom.xml

[image]

But when I package the project:

package by IDEA

[image]

It fails:

fail log

[image]

I want to know how to resolve this when the jar was not found in the maven repository.

Comment: I recommand you to copy-paste your build text and logs instead of screenshot. Your text will be mush more easier to read/use and won't be cropped.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define a systemPath for your dependencies, however it is only allowed for dependencies with a *system* `scope`. You must either:

- Remove the `systemPath` and use (or configure) a Maven repository from which your dependencies will be downloaded. If you use open source or public dependencies there are chances they will be available on the [Central Maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/repository/) by default.
- Define a system scope for your dependencies such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.someproject.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3/version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>...</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

If your dependencies are private or company-owned, I strongly advise you to configure your Maven repo for you and your team instead of using system dependencies. [Using system scope is deprecated](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies):

> ### System Dependencies
>
> Important note: This is marked deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use direct links to maven repository in your dependency statements? For example as here:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```